# Making modern (RAII) C++-code with Qt5

Tags: c++, c++14, pointers, qt, raii

I am fully aware that Qt is quite good with handling ownership in its object trees. The usual pattern seems to be to use a raw `new`, assigning the result to a raw pointer and then giving up the ownership with some `widget->add(...)` call.

This does not seem C++11/C++14, or modern, or RAII-style to me -- especially not in the light of the new [C++ Core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-introduction) and the [Guidelines Support library (GSL)](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-gsl).

I started using `unique_ptr` to be on the safe side during set-up. The `widget->add(...)` then  gets the `unique_ptr::release()`-result. So if anything goes awry it is still sure there is no leak. But because after `release()` the content of the `unique_ptr` is `nullptr` I stored its content non-owning (an "alias") in a separate variable for later use (like `conntect` and other method calls).

That looks quite ok to me in simple cases. But when I designed my first own Widget class I had a lot of boiler-plate code around all this `unique_ptr`/non-owning-alias.

Here is my header file:

```
// 005-my-window/my_window.hpp
#ifndef MY_WINDOW_HPP
#define MY_WINDOW_HPP
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QObject>
class MyWindow : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
private: // nicht selbst Besitzer dieser QWidgets:
    QLabel* label_ = nullptr;
    QPushButton* button0_ = nullptr;
    QPushButton* button1_ = nullptr;
    QVBoxLayout* layout_ = nullptr;
    int cnt_ = 0; // zählt die Klicks mit
private slots:
    void setText();
};
#endif // MY_WINDOW_HPP
```

And here the implementation:

```
// 005-my-window/my_window.cpp
#include "my_window.hpp"
#include <QApplication>
#include <memory>
MyWindow::MyWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget{parent}
{
    auto label = std::make_unique<QLabel>("old text");
    label_ = label.get();
    auto button0 = std::make_unique<QPushButton>("Increment");
    button0_ = button0.get();
    auto button1 = std::make_unique<QPushButton>("Quit");
    button1_ = button1.get();
    auto layout = std::make_unique<QVBoxLayout>(this);
    layout_ = layout.get();
    layout->addWidget(button0.release());
    layout->addWidget(button1.release());
    layout->addWidget(label.release());
    setLayout(layout.release());
    connect( button0_, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( setText() ) );
    connect( button1_, SIGNAL( clicked() ), qApp, SLOT( quit() ) );
}
void MyWindow::setText() {
    QString msg{"Label updated "};
    msg.append(QString{}.setNum(++cnt_));
    msg.append(" times");
    label_->setText(msg);
}
```

Well, I need the non-owning raw pointer members to the QWidgets for later use, obviously. But in the constructor I use my safe RAII `unique_ptr`-machinery to initialize them. Disadvantages:

- quite some boiler-plate per item for initialization
- initialization not done in c'tors init-section
- members are first ini'd with `nullptr` and later re-assigned with actual values.

Therefore I am only 70% satisfied with this code.

Is there a more comprehensive way to init Qt5 Widgets in a safe, modern RAII manner in C++14?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you actually encounter any leaks with the old model or is this purely a pre-emptive approach to prevent potential leaks?

Comment: @yuri Purely pre-emptive for academic reasons. Imagine I design a quite complicated widget on my own that I use all over the place. Maybe that widget throws exceptions (beyond bad_alloc) in its constructor when it fails to initialize (c++-core-guideline-ish). When I have several members of this widget in some big window and the third one throws an exception during its initialization -- I would leak the first two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in Qt, act like Qt.

Qt already has an ownership model, and it works by passing the parent object (as a raw pointer) in the constructor (so there's no window of exception-triggered leakage).  And Qt has its own weak pointers (including `QObjectPointer`).

I wouldn't try to outsmart Qt on pointer lifetime and ownership - but keep watching development, and if a future version of the library starts accepting smart pointers to transfer ownership, then reach out and grab it at that time!

In my personal opinion, the code you show is less clear than the Qt-native equivalent:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QObject>

class MyWindow : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
private:
    QLabel *const label;
    QPushButton *const button0;
    QPushButton *const button1;
    QVBoxLayout *const layout;
    int count = 0;
private slots:
    void setText();
};

#include <QApplication>
MyWindow::MyWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget{parent},
      label{new QLabel{"old text", this}},
      button0{new QPushButton{"Increment", this}},
      button1{new QPushButton{"Quit", this}},
      layout{new QVBoxLayout{this}}
{
    layout->addWidget(button0);
    layout->addWidget(button1);
    layout->addWidget(label);
    setLayout(layout);
    connect(button0, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyWindow::setText);
    connect(button1, &QPushButton::clicked, qApp, &QCoreApplication::quit);
}
void MyWindow::setText() {
    label->setText(QString{"Label updated %0 times"}.arg(++count));
}
```

Here, I've made the widget pointers const for safety, so we know that they will be valid for the lifetime of the `MyWindow` object.

I've also used the method-pointer version of `connect()` - I recommend this where practicable, to get more checking at compile time.  Connect by name only when you really have to, such as when you can't know the complete types of the objects you're connecting.  See also [Connecting overloaded signals and slots in Qt 5](//stackoverflow.com/q/16794695) if you have trouble with overloads.

---

Your code and comments suggest that you're concerned about leaking memory if an exception is thrown in an initializer.  For example, consider a failure to allocate/construct `button0` after `label` was successfully created; will `label` then be left in limbo?  Although our `~MyWindow()` destructor is not called (and we don't even need a non-default one), its superclass destructors will be.  And that includes the `~QObject` destructor, which deletes its children.  We know that `label` will be deleted, because its constructor returned (and adding itself as a child is among the first things it does).

None of this would be true (and we would not be exception-safe) if we forgot to include the optional `parent` parameter (`this`) when constructing `label`; if we were to initialize it without a parent and then its `setParent()` method in the body of the constructor, we would have a gap where Qt wouldn't own it properly.

We can demonstrate this by wrapping one or more of the allocations in a function.  The following code allows you to experiment with throwing exceptions for the different child objects:

```
int alloc_succeeds = 3;
#include <stdexcept>
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T *createWidget(Args... args)
{
    if (--alloc_succeeds < 0)
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    return new T{args...};
}

#define PARENT this
//#define PARENT nullptr

#include <QApplication>
MyWindow::MyWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget{parent},
      label{createWidget<QLabel>("old text", PARENT)},
      button0{createWidget<QPushButton>("Increment", PARENT)},
      button1{createWidget<QPushButton>("Quit", PARENT)},
      layout{createWidget<QVBoxLayout>(PARENT)}
{
```

Change the value of `alloc_succeeds` to determine how many constructors are successful.  If we run the code under Valgrind, we see that by changing `PARENT` to `nullptr`, we can get our objects to leak (we also see some of the leaks of Qt itself, so it's helpful to run both to eliminate false positives).

Comment: 1) Yes, I forgot about the c'tor param parent, thx. 2) I am always a bit confused with layouts. They can't be parents because they aren't widgets. Thx for unconfusing me. 3) Problem with raw new in c'tor-init-section: if the 3rd field throws, then the 1st and 2nd pointer are _not_ _deleted_! This is a no-go for my RAII C++ style. And no magic Qt-mechanism can come to the rescue (that I can see). If there were a rule "QObject constructrors may not throw" (`noexcept`?) I would be more happy. But this code, I am afraid, I consider unsafe in the general case. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, I just had the brainwave that it _is_ safe to raw-new a Widget, if (and only if) it gets a parent as a c'tor argument.

Comment: It's a bit surprising if you're not used to Qt; I've updated to show how you can demonstrate what works and what doesn't.  As you say, it's safe **only if** you provide the parent before anything else may throw (passing it as an argument to the constructor is safe and convenient).